# Implementing Facebook Audien Network Ads for iOS Apps in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook-audience-network

There are only guide for implement Facebook Audien Network ads for IOS app in Obj C:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/get-started/ios

How can I get document for Swift?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's in Obj C, but Here is a swift guide tutorial. [https://www.appcoda.com/facebook-ads-integration/]. But in older swift version. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add `Facebook Audience Network`

```
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
```

Step 2: import `FBAudienceNetwork`

```
import FBAudienceNetwork
```

Step 2: Add `Delegate` to your ViewController

```
class FBInterstitialDemo: UIViewController, FBInterstitialAdDelegate {
}
```

Step 3: Create `FBInterstitialAd` instance

```
let interstitialFBAD: FBInterstitialAd = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "282907702901663_391523248706774")
```

Step 4: set delegate for `FBInterstitialAd`

```
interstitialFBAD.delegate = self;
```

Step 5: Load Ad

```
interstitialFBAD.load()
```

Step 6: Show Ad, if the Ad is loaded && isValid

```
if interstitialAd.isAdValid {
            interstitialAd.show(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
```

Here is a demo ViewController for reference:

```
import UIKit
import FBAudienceNetwork

let interstitialFBAD: FBInterstitialAd = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "your_placement_id_here")

class FBInterstitialDemo: UIViewController, FBInterstitialAdDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        interstitialFBAD.delegate = self;
        interstitialFBAD.load()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func interstitialAdDidLoad(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd) {
        if interstitialAd.isAdValid {
            interstitialAd.show(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
            
        }
        
        func interstitialAd(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error)
        }
        
        func interstitialAdDidClick(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd) {
            print("Did tap on ad")
        }


        func interstitialAdDidClose(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd) {
            print("Did close ad")
        }
    

}
```

posting after so long, because i could not find a tutorial in swift to integrate Facebook Audience Network